# How to download captcha image in JAVA?I am able to get image url in HttpURLConnection object

Tags: java, http, httprequest, httpresponse, urlconnection

I have written a JAVA program to get captcha image from a secure site. The aim is to download that captcha image and display the user in own customised window.

For that I am able to successfully get the captcha image in `HttpURLConnection` object (e.g. **"http://enquiry.indianrail.gov.in/ntes/CaptchaServlet?action=getNewCaptchaImg&t=1430205579014"** ). However I am struggling to get a way to save this image in local disk. How to parse this url and save captcha image?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can read the image from URL

```
BufferedImage img = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL(getCodeBase(), "examples/strawberry.jpg");
    img = ImageIO.read(url);
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

`getCodeBase()` will return the URL you can also directly pass it , Now after having BufferedImage instance you can save it , display it whatever you want to do !

**[More on Reading/Loading an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)**

Answer (score 0):

You should have the image as a stream, so you just need to convert your inpustream image to file.
See an example here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-file-in-java/